# How can I filter a for loop based on the value of a field?

Tags: templating, elementquery

How can I filter a `for loop` based on the value of a field?

I tried `filterByValue`, but I do not know how to construct the statement.

This is NOT a category field.

I have this...

```
{% for line in craft.entries.section('docs').filterByVale('account: 05').all() %}
    <a href="{{ line.url }}">{{line.lineItemTitle}} ({{line.lineItemTitle}})</a>, 
{% endfor %}
```

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't filter a `loop` but you can attach certain criteria in your `ElementQuery`. `craft.entries` returns you an object of type `EntryQuery` ([link to docs](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/element-queries.md)). You can search for specific entries based on different criterias by calling magic methods or function in your `Query` object.

For example: `section('docs')` will return only entries in the section `docs`. You can attach any field handle that is in your field layout as well.. In your case `account('05')`.

```
{% for line in craft.entries.section('docs').account('05').all() %}
     <a href="{{ line.url }}">{{line.lineItemTitle}} ({{line.lineItemTitle}})</a>, 
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to search for multiple values you can include them as array or comma separated string.

```
craft.entries
    .section(['section1', 'section2')
    .account('and, >=5, <=10')
    .anotherField('or, 3, 5')
    .someThingElse(['or' ,3 , 5])
    .all()
```

You can see all available syntax examples in the [DB::parseParam()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-db.html#parseParam()-detail) function